# DataFrame.to_sql Need to specify partition columns because the destination table is partitioned

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

Do you have any idea how can I insert a python dataframe data to a partitioned sql?

This code is working for non-partitioned table.

```
df.to_sql('my_table', engine, if_exists='append', method='multi')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem, here is my solution.
First, insert the data to a temporary table without partitions, and then select all data from the temporary table to insert into the specified partition.

```
from pyhive import hive

conn = hive.connect(host='localhost',
                    port=10000,
                    username='your_username',
                    database='your_database')

df.to_sql(f'xxxx_tmp', hive_engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, method='multi')
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(f"""insert overwrite table xxxx partition(dt=20240326) select * from xxxx_tmp""")
```